# Iterative functions that are adjustable for pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, function, pandas, loops, numpy

I've built a sort of financial forecasting model. It's very long and I'm unsure of what kind of function I would use to do it. Basically I need to calculate the projected spending for the year based on the previous year and then re-prioritize the list so things that were purchased the previous fiscal year fall to the bottom. I'm trying to calculate for 30 years. I understand this can be done with a loop, however, the budget available for expenditures changes from year to year.

Here is an example of the the dataframe I'm trying to achieve:

```
    Budget_Y1 = 400.00
    Budget_Y2 = 300.00

  DF1
Part           RankY1     CostY1     SpendY1    RankY2  CostY2   SpendY2

Transmission      1         400       400         4         0       0
Tires             2         200        0          1        200     200
Windshield        3         100        0          2        100     100
Wipers            4          20        0          3         20      0
```

My data is ultimately much more complicated than this, involving millions of rows.

Right now I calculate each year individually based on the previous year so that I can easily change the budget available for each year in order to run different funding scenarios.

My questions is simply is there a function (or type of function) that can calculate  each year based on the previous year with a different budget for each year so I don't have to hand code all calculations?

Am I looking at a generator to do something like this or some other function?
essentially it would be similar to an amoritzation calculator of sorts.

Right now I use this code over and over thirty years out to get the cost for each year since the budget is different every year:

```
   df1.loc[(df1['RankY2']<4), 'CostY2'] = df1['CostY1']

   df1['Spend_Y2']= np.where((df1.Cost_Y2.cumsum(
                                   <=budget_Y2), df1.Cost_Y2 ,0)

   ...Repeat some other calculations...

   ...do new priority calculation...

    df1 = df1.sort_values('RankY3', ascending = False)
```

Edited for a more clear example.

Comment: What is the data structure of each year?

Comment: a simple numerical example would help bring better reproducible code

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal  I edited the example it's a dataframe in pandas. Does this help?

Comment: @chrisckwong821 Edited for numerical example. I also added a simplified version of the code I'm using but I have to repeat it for every year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still quite unclear on what you are trying to achieve.

Here is a loop over your functions though:

```
def budget_calculations(df, year_budget):
    df.loc[(df['RankY2']<4), 'CostY2'] = df['CostY1']

    df['Spend_Y2'] = np.where((df.Cost_Y2.cumsum(<=year_budget), df.Cost_Y2, 0)

    return df.sort_values('RankY3', ascending = False)


for budget in budget_list:
    df = budget_calculation(df, budget)
```

This will iterate through the budget_list (e.g. `[100, 250, 300]`) and output a new pd.DataFrame to be used in the next iteration.

If you want to calculate the budget in each iteration:

```
# iterate 30 times
for n in range(30):
    budget = calculate_budget(df, budget)
```

And have calculate_budget `return` the next year budget.

Finally you can return both the items and the budget like so:

```
budget_each_year = []
for n in range(30):
    df, budget = calculate_year(df, budget)
    budget_each_year.append(budget)
```

This will create a list of the budgets for all iterations.